# Deja-Dup did not show success message

Tags: 16.04, deja-dup, luks, duplicity

In a few hours I go travel with my laptop, so last night I launched a DejaDup backup, from my laptop to an external drive that I will leave at a safe place.

**Problem**: DejaDup did not display any message like "Backup successful" or anything. Instead, the progress window has disappeared, and only this window is left:

[image: Deja-Dup Last backup was 30 days ago]

Duplicity does not seem to be running:

```
$ ps aux |grep dup
nico      2913  0.0  0.1 663192 23476 ?        Sl    1月16   0:02 deja-dup-preferences
nico      3207  0.0  0.0 439052  7480 ?        Sl    1月16   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor
```

My data is 1TB (virtual machines, movies, programs, lots of source code), and the destination folder of the backup now contains 300 GB of DejaDup files up to `duplicity-full.20170115T132449Z.vol5593.difftar.gz`. I actually had the exact same problem two days ago and then the backup was only 100 GB, so I am not sure that these 300 GB contain everything.

When I try to verify the backup, I get this (by the way I don't know why it is asking for a passphrase, since the backup is not encrypted):

```
$ duplicity verify "file:///media/nico/externaldrive/deja-dup/" /home/nico/
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session
Last full backup date: none
GnuPG passphrase for decryption: 
Cannot use empty passphrase with symmetric encryption!  Please try again.
```

**Question**: How to fix the problem and get reliable backups?

It was working fine before, and this behavior started after I decided to reformat my external drive from ext4 to LUKS+ext4, with the same disk label. I always mount the disk before starting Deja-Dup so theoretically that should not be a problem.